# In which direction(s) do the electric and magnetic field lines of electromagnetic waves point?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

Most diagrams of EM waves show arrows pointing away from (perpendicular to) the axial line of propagation, but I am not sure if this just shows the amplitude of the B and E fields or their lines of force as well...

[image: wiki em wave]

I saw one diagram that showed the electric and magnetic field lines pointing parallel to the direction of propagation, instead of orthogonally, but reversing direction every half-wave...

Comment: There is no line of propagation (although there is a *direction* of propagation). This is a plane wave and the wavefronts are planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in this diagram we are presented with a plane electromagnetic wave whose $\vec{E}$ field is given by
$$\vec{E} = E_0 \cos(kz-\omega t) \hat{e}_x$$

Now let's try to understand this equation. First you will notice that the $\vec E$ is directed only in the $\hat e_x$ direction. So all the arrows representing **$\vec E$ must be parallel to the $x$-axis.** So it is actual vectors of electric field that are pointed as shown in the diagram and their length represents their intensity.

Next we can do is to fix $t$ to analyze the field in space at some specific moment.For $t=0$ the equation becomes:
$$\vec E = E_0 \cos(kz) \hat e_x$$
This means that if you move along the $z$-axis, the intensity of the field will vary. Cosine has maxima at $2n\pi, n \in \mathbb Z$ and minima at $(2n+1)\pi, n \in \mathbb Z$. This means that $\vert \vec E \vert$ has maxima at $z= \frac{2\pi}{k}\cdot n$ and minima ($\vec E$ is directed along negative $\hat e_x$ direction) at $z = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{k}$. This is exactly what you can see in the diagram. Even though $\vec E \ || \ \hat e_x$ at every point in space, the intensity of $\vec E$ is distributed *like cosine* along $z$-axis. Another thing to be aware of is that because nothing depends on $y$, you can translate this cosine along $y$-axis to get something like this:
[image]
*blue = x; red = y; green = z*

*This shows only the intensity of field at all points on the gray plane. Exact same result you would get for any plane parallel to it.*

And finally, at some fixed point $z=0$, field changes with time as follows:
$$\vec E(t) = E_0 \cos(-\omega t) \hat e_x$$
So again, just like a cosine.

Maybe it would be helpful to think of each point in space as a seat on a stadium, and every fan is the electric field vector. Now the fans together decide to perform a stadium wave.

- every fan only stands up or sits down remaining in the vertical position, just like the $\vec E$ field is always directed along $x$-axis here
- all the fans having seats one above the other always stand and sit at the same time, just like $\vec E$ is totally independent of $y$ direction
- because of coordination of all fans, the *wave* travels along the stadium, just like the field wave does along $z$-axis.

> I saw one diagram that showed the electric and magnetic field lines pointing parallel to the direction of propagation, instead of orthogonally, but reversing direction every half-wave...

As far as I know, Maxwell's equations tell us that EM waves can only be transverse, never longitudinal in vacuum at least. Suppose we had $\vec E$ field pointing in $z$ direction while also traveling in the same direction:

$$\vec E = E_0 \cos(kz-\omega t) \hat e_z \\ \implies \nabla \cdot \vec E = -E_0 k \sin(kz-\omega t) \not \equiv 0$$

But in vacuum where there are no charges floating around, Gauss' law gives us:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} = 0$$

Hence this wave contradicts the first Maxwell equation in vacuum (though not necessarily elsewhere).