# How can we visualize electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

In so many classes I’ve been told that light is nothing more than an electromagnetic wave. While this makes sense, it’s never been nearly as clear as imagining a static charge. At every point in space surrounding the static charge we can assign a vector representing the electric field. What about light? I know Maxwell's equations for $\rho=0$ give us something like $E=A\cos(kx-\omega t)$, but I feel there is something not being explicitly stated. It’s not like $x$ can assume any value, correct? I’d assume $x$ would be confined to the photon's trajectory. Otherwise, what does this equation even give us? It would imply that there’s an electric field present everywhere always. I’ve seen animations of electromagnetic waves orthogonal to each other on an axis, but I couldn’t imagine that the entire axis has an electric field, and also have trouble thinking about how the waves are shown in two dimensions.

So to quickly state my question, if we took snapshots of a photon and could see the electromagnetic wave at all points in space in each, what would we see? Would the field only exist at the singular point the photon resides at, would there be a field surrounding the photon (in the same way the electric field of a static charge does)? Does the field trail behind the photon as it travels? Etc.

If I’m not wrong, Maxwell's equations and the equation for electromagnetic radiation predated quantum theory, so how was this equation interpreted then, with the assumption the particle would always assume a definite position?

Comment: *It’s not like x can assume any value, correct?* No, incorrect. Electromagnetic fields, like all fields, have a value at every point.

Comment: "It would imply that there’s an electric field present everywhere always." --- Yup.

Comment: More things to blow your mind: It’s not like every charged particle has its own field. There is only *one* electromagnetic field filling the universe. All charges in the universe affect it. All photons in the universe are quanta of this one universal field.

Comment: @Ghoster what’s a better way to word it? I’m aware of this I just don’t really know a better way to say it… “excitation in the EM field due to…” would be better? It feels a little long

Comment: @Ghoster So when you comment “the electric field takes on a value everywhere” I’m not sure if you’re circumventing my question or if this answers it… sure the EM field has a value at every point, but does light change it the same way that a static charge does

Comment: What sentence are you trying to reword? I think what you are asking is reasonably clear.

Comment: @Ghoster and before I get the comment, I’ll change my wording again: light is a manifestation of an excitation in the EM field. Great, now how can we describe that disturbance? The electric field around a static charge is described by coloumbs law, and we can visualize it nicely—what does this look like for a photon?

Comment: *Does light change it the same way that a static charge does* No. A static charge has a static field. A light wave is a waving field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147363/discussion-between-user62783-and-ghoster).

Comment: A linearly-polarized EM plane wave looks like what Michael Seifert shows in his answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/772165/where-are-the-magnetic-poles-in-an-electromagnetic-wave/772166#772166). The vast majority of internet images of EM waves are horribly misleading as they only show the field along a line,

Comment: "if we took snapshots of a photon and could see the EM wave at all points in space in each" mixes up two mathematical models for electromagneitc radiation. Photons are in the quantum  mechanical model , the EM wave is in the classical model. One cannot take "snapshots" of photons, as in QM probabilities are involved in the position of the photon.

Comment: @annav okay that definitely clears up a lot of confusion. If I rephrased my question to “if we take snapshots of the wave at every instant” would this be better? I don’t mean that in a physical way as in actually trying to make a measurement on the system but like we’re just imagining the math. Other answers I got indicated the wave permeates all of space at every instant but I find this very hard to imagine/believe

Comment: well, the mathematics of the wave equation  resulting from Maxwell'' equations are a way of "seeing the wave", as the model fits very well all measurements of electromagnetic radiation,

Comment: @annav that’s what I’m talking about, in other words if I went to matlab to make a plot, I’d plot something like Acos(kt-wx) on, say, the y and z axis corresponding to the electric/magnetic field vectors (so 2 vectors for each point) for some EM wave traveling in the x direction. But this wave doesn’t have any y or z dependance, so this means that the entire 3 dimensional grid (aka all of space) is filled with vectors, and in each y/z cross section all these vectors are equal? And of course you could make an animation to show these vectors changing in time

Comment: @annav I used to think that the variables in the wave equation were constrained to some trajectory, so we only had one “line” with plane waves, but ghoster was telling me this isn’t the case and that the plane waves exist in all of space. This is a much weirder concept to me, thinking of all of space filled these standing waves

Comment: @annav and also since these equations result from the absence of charge, do they need something to “produce them” (like the electric field of a moving charge), or do we just consider them always present (waves of all frequencies/amplitudes/phases/directions of propagation), or does it need something to create it?

Comment: You are asking for a course in classical electrodynamics to really understand what is mathematical modeling and what is observations. It is not possible to explain in the comments of a question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147377/discussion-between-user62783-and-anna-v).

Answer (score 0):

**EM radiation** in the range of visible light arises from transitions to lower energy levels of electrons around the atomic nucleus. This happens - for which Einstein was awarded the Nobel Prize - quantised. The quanta were later called **photons**. However, the spectrum of EM radiation is much larger and also includes nuclear processes (shorter-wave radiation). Long-wave radiation is also assigned to the EM spectrum, which produces **EM waves** through the joint periodic excitation of electrons in antennas.

The photons contained in all EM radiation travel forward at the speed of light until they encounter an obstacle (another electron). While mechanical waves (sound, water waves) require a medium, this is not necessary for photons and is even counterproductive.

The periodic and synchronous acceleration of electrons in an antenna rod creates a **radio wave** (which is modulated and can thus transmit information to the receiver). Hertz generated and measured radio waves in the laboratory. He found that these waves have a **magnetic field and an electric field component** that periodically merge into each other.

Hertz did not know anything about photons. Today we know that the radio waves observed by Hertz consist of zillions of photons that are created by the excitation of electrons. While **thermally excited radiation** (which makes up the majority of the radiation surrounding us) produces photons chaotically, this happens for radio waves through the acceleration of electrons in the same direction. This creates a polarised field of photons whose total electric and magnetic field components are perpendicular to each other.

The macroscopic field components of the radio wave are the sum of the field components of the photons generating it.

> In so many classes I’ve been told that light is nothing more than an electromagnetic wave.

This is not precise enough. Light is EM radiation. Search for the source of the radiation and you end up with the excitation of electrons. The filament in the light bulb emits photons because electrons are moved through the wire by a potential difference. Through multiple collisions at the atomic level, the electrons chaotically accelerate and by this chaotically radiate photons of different frequencies. No one can observe a wave from this, not to mention measure it directly. The only thing invoked is the phenomenon of wavelike intensity distribution of light behind slits. However, this represents a deduction and is not a direct measurement of the wave property as Hertz could measure it for radio waves.

> So to quickly state my question, if we took snapshots of a photon and could see the EM wave at all points in space in each, what would we see?

The snapshots of a photon will show the periodic transition of its magnetic field component into its electric field component and back into its magnetic field component and so on. This will be the case for further photons in each spatial direction in which the source emits photons.

This is also true for radio waves. Only that here the photons are polarized (their electric field components are parallel to the antenna rod and their magnetic ones are perpendicular to it) and the number of emitted photons varies periodically (which is based on the fact that the wave generator must be operated with alternating voltage).

I apologize for this long answer, but I could not encompass the facets of the question in a shorter way.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8hPY.png

Answer (score 0):

The equation $E=Acos(kx-wt)$ describes a, plane wave, meaning one that extends infinitely in the $y$ and $z$ directions and propagates in the $x$ direction. And each plane of constant $x$ has an identical field value $\vec E$.

This equation is this a simplified model that never exists in practice, but it exists approximately if you restrict your inquiry to a small enough region – say, a 10 cm x 10 cm square (in the y and z directions) that is about 100 km (x direction) from a radio antenna source.

This is probably the best visualization of a classical EM wave

[image: from Wiki]

From [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation)

But keep in mind the red and blue peaks and troughs are not physically extended in space. They are showing the magnitude and direction of the field vector at a *point* on the x axis.

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but you say "it never exists in practice"--what is this due to? Also, I dont understand how the plane wave equation is crude (im assuming thats what you mean by simplified)--in a vacuum, its exactly what maxwells equations predict and from my understanding maxwells equations are regarded as one of the best models we have. Thanks for any help

Comment: Maxwell's Eqns are correct, but the boundary conditions we choose to solve them in closed form are an idealization.  In order to have a true plane wave you would need an infinite wall of charge that oscillates from + to – all in unison.  This clearly doesn't exist anywhere in reality.  But it is a good *model* for a wave coming from a cylindrical or spherical source as long as you are not too close to the source.

Comment: It's the same as modeling the Earth's gravitational field as a constant downward $\vec g$ with magnitude 9.8 m/s$^2$ everywhere. This works well enough in many cases, as long as we do not consider a region of the Earth that is too large, or too far above the surface.